# Lock Screen and Prompt for Password

Tags: windows, locking, screen, password-protection, prompt

I need to create a program that can lock a Windows screen and prompt for a username and password.

It can be in any language but something without .net would be preferable in case I were to want to run it in an older version of Windows or WinPE.

I need it to not allow any other input in any way until the correct username and password have been put in.

It does not matter is the screen behind the prompt is blacked out or if it shows the desktop but doesn't allow the user to click.

Does anyone have any suggestions where I should begin?

Comment: It would help to show what you have tried, what searches you've done, etc.  You may wish to read [this excellent article on how to write good technical questions](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: I would tell you what I have done by have not done anything.  I am merely asking for some direction.  I cannot do it in C# since WinPE doesn't have .Net so I was wondering if someone knew that it could be done to tell me what language and maybe what providers to research to get me started.  I am not asking for the code as that would slow my learning but there is no point in learning Java, PHP, or C++ if Perl is the only language in which it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with this knowledge (sounds rather disruptive to the user imo), but you may be able to use the following knowledge to your advantage:

- pressing CTRL+ESC simulates the Windows key
- Windows key + L locks the computer

Comment: well i want to secure a WinPE that we have created with tools to assist with administrating a computer.  It has malware fixing tools like Malwarebytes and other things.  I want to leave the .wim on the computer but at the same time we don't want someone unauthorized to boot to the .wim file and getting access to the data.